# After "legitimately" rooting an HTC phone, how do I get SuperUser to work?

Tags: rooting, root-access, superuser, setcpu

I went through [HTC's official rooting steps](http://htcdev.com/bootloader/) which I've discovered is unusual because it means I didn't instantly start with a special rom that has SuperUser installed by default.  I installed Superuser from the Play store, but when I run something like SetCPU, I just get "SetCPU can't get root permission.  Make sure to set it in superuser."  I don't get the promised sudden prompt from SuperUser.  Is there a special way to install SuperUser that I should be using?

Comment: An unlocked bootloader is the precondition to mod a phone. It's not the same as having root it just allows you to install a custom recovery and a different boot.img. You need to flash a CWM recovery and a compatible gain-root.zip or just start all over and install a real ROM like CyanogenMod (hope your model's supported).

Comment: SuperUser (or SuperSU) needs to be installed as *system app* (i.e. in `/system/apps`), which is done in the way ce4 indicated. If afterwards there comes an updated version, it *then* can be installed from the market directly.

Comment: I actually went through the bootloader unlocking process just to get the privilege saving things from the browser to the external SD card (which required running a full shell and worked).  I don't really want to install Cyanogen or anything.  If the phone isn't really rooted, I guess all those cool apps are still off limits.  @ce4 Why not make that your real answer so I can give you the checkmark?

Comment: I typed that on my mobile where I prefer leaving comments (not so much formatting. Forgot to move it to the answer section). Moved.

Answer (score 2):

An unlocked bootloader is the precondition to mod a phone. It's not the same as having root; it just allows you to install a custom recovery and a different boot.img. You need to flash a CWM recovery and a compatible gain-root.zip or just start all over and install a real ROM like CyanogenMod (hope your model's supported)

What you gain from having an unlocked bootloader: fastboot access.
These are the most important commands ('boot' may be missing though):

- `fastboot boot boot.img` (boot to *boot.img* without flashing)
- `fastboot flash recovery CWM.img` (install a custom recovery)

What you have to do to gain root:
If your HTC supports the `fastboot boot 'foo.img'` command, use this to launch a temporary ClockworkMod recovery from [here](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/) or find a suitable CWM in your phone's XDA forum. If your model only supports the `fastboot flash 'recovery.img'`, you have to install the recovery permanently to the phone's recovery partition. After that you have to install SuperSU (see this [thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053), search for CWM installable ZIP: CWM-SuperSU-v0.98.zip) via the recovery's *install zip from sdcard* or *adb sideload* feature. This pushes both the **su** binary and the **Superuser.apk** to your phone. After that you have root and can enjoy all those [cool root apps](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/09/top-root-apps-every-rooted-user-should-know-about-part-6-apps-42-49/).